# Develop without Material Design

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I'm using Android Studio to develop some applications and I have Material Design even in Android 2.3! Can anyone suggest me another application that didn't **FORCE** Material Design? Or a way that remove material design?
Thanks

Comment: The keyword here is "I think" - meaning this is speculative. Please dig deeper to truly find the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Can you prove it's the Material Design? Anyways, you may set the compikeSdk and targetSdk to whatever the last API number was that didn't include the material components (I think that's Kitkat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement for you to implement the Material Design aesthetic on any application, let alone the one that you are describing.

Moreover, Material Design is not responsible for your application size, any more than the white pixels on this Web page makes the page fat.

You did not provide any information about your application's setup. My guess is that you are using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.). Those add ~1MB to an app's release size, and `appcompat-v7` is what gives your app the Material Design look on older devices.

You do not have to use `appcompat-v7`. Simply remove it from your `app/build.gradle` file and remove any place where your code is leveraging it:

- Replace `AppCompatActivity` with `Activity`
- Replace `Theme.AppCompat` with other themes based on Android version
- Replace the `app:` prefix in your menu resources with `android:`
- And so on

Depending upon your app's configuration, you might be pulling in other libraries that themselves depend upon `appcompat-v7` (e.g., `com.android.support:design`). You would need to get rid of those as well.

This will take some work for an existing application. Usually, it is easier to opt out of using `appcompat-v7` at the outset.

[This GitHub repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) contains hundreds of sample apps from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android). Most of these do not use `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: I take care of this. But anyway I just want to develop without Material Design.